# How to make SQL code for getting top 100 distributors faster?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this database based on this file [sql file](https://github.com/Abdqadr1/naxum/blob/main/nxm_assessment.sql). The database contains random data, not real data.

The goal is to get the top 100 distributors with the most sales. Sales are the total amount of orders that have been purchased by the customers and distributors they have referred and if 2 or more Distributors have achieved the same amount of sales, they would have the same rank.

[image]

I already have working sql code but it is slow. It takes about 4 minutes to complete.

Here is my MySQL code;

```
WITH items_total AS
(
    SELECT 
        (oi.quantity * p.price) AS total, oi.order_id 
    FROM 
        order_items oi
    INNER JOIN 
        products p on p.id = oi.product_id
),
orders_total AS
(
    SELECT 
        o.id, o.purchaser_id, SUM(it.total) AS total
    FROM 
        orders o
    INNER JOIN 
        items_total it ON it.order_id = o.id 
    GROUP BY 
        o.id
), 
distributors AS
(
    SELECT 
        u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name, c.name
    FROM 
        users u 
    INNER JOIN 
        user_category uc ON uc.user_id = u.id
    INNER JOIN 
        categories c ON c.id = uc.category_id
    WHERE 
        c.id = 1 
    GROUP BY u.id
)
SELECT
    d.first_name, d.last_name, 
    SUM(ot.total) AS total_sales, d.id, 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY total_sales DESC) AS 'rank'
FROM  
    distributors d
INNER JOIN 
    users uu ON uu.referred_by = d.id
INNER JOIN
    orders_total ot ON ot.purchaser_id = uu.id
GROUP BY
    d.id 
ORDER BY 
    total_sales DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

How can I make it run faster?

Comment: how many records do you have in the tables?

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample input data, and the execution plan for the given query

Comment: Users table: 18k+
orders table: 4234
order_items table: 7698
product: 80

Comment: Users are categoriezed in to two: customer and distributors. users refer another users. I ran the code in xampp and from my laravel project. Its slow

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, please don't forget to share the execution plan

Comment: @AbdQadr Please post TEXT results of EXPLAIN SELECT (your query) so we can see the execution plan.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE ` for each table.

Comment: See [_Many-to-many_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) for a better indexing of many-to-many tables such as `user_categories`.

Comment: @RickJames SQL code for creating all the tables is [here](https://github.com/Abdqadr1/naxum/blob/main/nxm_assessment.sql)

Comment: **Please add all clarification to your question by editing it** - don't put it anywhere else

Answer (score 1):

I see a `PRIMARY KEY` on one table; each table needs a PK.  I see no other `INDEXes`.

The performance of queries depends on Indexes.

Comment: thank you. I added a primary key to all other tables. It took less than a second.

Comment: The power of indexing!  (In MySQL, a `PRIMARY KEY` is a unique index.)